# Classifying singularities of a function

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the singular part at each of the isolated singular points in C
$$\frac{(z^2-1)(z-2)^2}{\sin\pi z}$$
I am trying to manipulate the function in a way that I can identify the singularities but I am unsuccessful.

Comment: By singular part do you mean principal part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll get a singularity whenever the denominator is zero.  So every integer is a singularity.